# Region Growing Method doesn't work for images with Histogram Equalization applied

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to apply a Region Growing algorithm found on the FEX. The algorithm is as follows:

```
    function J=regiongrowing(I)
if(exist('reg_maxdist','var')==0), reg_maxdist=0.2; end
if(exist('y','var')==0), figure, imshow(I,[]); [y,x]=getpts; y=round(y(1)); x=round(x(1)); end

J = zeros(size(I)); % Output 
Isizes = size(I); % Dimensions of input image

reg_mean = I(x,y); % The mean of the segmented region
reg_size = 1; % Number of pixels in region

% Free memory to store neighbours of the (segmented) region
neg_free = 10000; neg_pos=0;
neg_list = zeros(neg_free,3); 

pixdist=0; % Distance of the region newest pixel to the regio mean

% Neighbor locations (footprint)
neigb=[-1 0; 1 0; 0 -1;0 1];

% Start regiogrowing until distance between regio and posible new pixels become
% higher than a certain treshold
while(pixdist<reg_maxdist&&reg_size<numel(I))

    % Add new neighbors pixels
    for j=1:4,
        % Calculate the neighbour coordinate
        xn = x +neigb(j,1); yn = y +neigb(j,2);

        % Check if neighbour is inside or outside the image
        ins=(xn>=1)&&(yn>=1)&&(xn<=Isizes(1))&&(yn<=Isizes(2));

        % Add neighbor if inside and not already part of the segmented area
        if(ins&&(J(xn,yn)==0)) 
                neg_pos = neg_pos+1;
                neg_list(neg_pos,:) = [xn yn I(xn,yn)]; J(xn,yn)=1;
        end
    end

    % Add a new block of free memory
    if(neg_pos+10>neg_free), neg_free=neg_free+10000; neg_list((neg_pos+1):neg_free,:)=0; end

    % Add pixel with intensity nearest to the mean of the region, to the region
    dist = abs(neg_list(1:neg_pos,3)-reg_mean);
    [pixdist, index] = min(dist);
    J(x,y)=2; reg_size=reg_size+1;

    % Calculate the new mean of the region
    reg_mean= (reg_mean*reg_size + neg_list(index,3))/(reg_size+1);

    % Save the x and y coordinates of the pixel (for the neighbour add proccess)
    x = neg_list(index,1); y = neg_list(index,2);

    % Remove the pixel from the neighbour (check) list
    neg_list(index,:)=neg_list(neg_pos,:); neg_pos=neg_pos-1;
end

% Return the segmented area as logical matrix
J=J>1;
```

However, when I try and apply the method to an image with a Histogram Equalization, the result is white blocks. If I use the method on an image that hasn't had the Histogram Equalization applied to it, it works perfectly fine. Is there a way to have the method work on an image that has the Histogram Equalization applied?

This is what I am doing:

```
cookiesImage = histeq(im2double(imread('cookies.png')));
test = regiongrowing(cookiesImage);
figure, imshow(test + cookiesImage);
```

Comment: provide the images

Comment: `imhist` output is a 1-D histogram, not an image. What do you expect to get from this?

Comment: @Bentoy13 I am not sure why I posted imhist when I was using histeq to prepare the image. I’ve edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I am just thinking logically through this - could it be the reason I am seeing white blocks for the pixels rather than the red is that the pixel densities are too close together from white to gray? If so, is there a way to adjust this?

Comment: change this line `cookiesImage = histeq(im2double(imread('cookies.png')));` to `cookiesImage = histeq(double(imread('cookies.png')));` OR multiply the `cookiesImage` with 255 and try again.It might work for you